# count-up effect for a textView in Android

Tags: android, count, textview

I am working on an app that counts the number of words in a paragraphs/page of text.

After the scanning is done,  I would love to show the output total number of words after the number goes from 0 to TOTAL (No of Words).

Example: `So, for 100 words: 0..wait..1..wait..2..wait..3..wait..4..wait..5,6,7,8,9 10.......99,100 and then STOP`.

I have tried a couple of different techniques:

```
 TextView sentScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sentScore);

                long freezeTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

                for (int i = 0; i < sent; i++) {
                    if ((SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - freezeTime) > 500) {
                        sentScore.setText(sent.toString());
                    }
                }
```

Also I tried this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < sent; i++) { 
        // try {
            Thread.sleep(500);

        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            sentScore.setText(i.toString()); 
        } 
    }
```

But nothing is helped me. I am sure these are both completely amateur attempts.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The below code will help you current gap is 100 ms but you can change as per your convenience

```
for (int i = 0; i < sent; i++) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            sentScore.setText(sent.toString());
        }
    }, 100 * i);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this code spawn a lot of handlers increasing memory consumption. Also, there is no way to interrupt background work. Its not a professional solution, this should be done as Google recommends using AsyncTask which are cancelable in case that activity go to pause. Also it doesnt work as expected because all handlers are executed after 100ms, time should be 100*i instead of 100.

Answer (score -1):

In android you are supposed to use AsyncTask for this kind of work

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
private class CountUpTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private TextView textview;
    private int current, total, interval;

    public CountUpTask(TextView textview, int total, int interval) {
        this.textview = textview;
        this.current = 0;
        this.total = total;
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground() {
        while(this.current < this.total){
          Thread.sleep(this.interval);
          this.current++;
          publishProgress(this.current);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        this.textview.setText("0");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        this.textview.setText(progress+"");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute() {

    }
}
```

As you can see, doInBackground is executed in a background thread, onPrexcute, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute are executed in UI thread, allowing you to update the UI.

```
CountUpTask countUpTask = new CountUpTask ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.sentScore), sent, 500);
countUpTask.execute();
```